# WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE PHP Example

Tags: php, walmart-api

Walmart provides a java example to generate a signature that is required for their new apis:

> The signature generated using the private key and signing the values of consumer id, timestamp and key version. The TTL of this signature is 180 seconds. Post that, the API Proxy will throw a "timestamp expired" error.

Java Code

```
//package com.walmart.platform.common;

import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.security.KeyRep;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class SignatureGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SignatureGenerator generator = new SignatureGenerator();

        String consumerId = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        String priviateKeyVersion = "1";
        String privateKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

        long intimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("consumerId: " + consumerId);
        System.out.println("intimestamp: " + intimestamp);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("WM_CONSUMER.ID", consumerId);
        map.put("WM_CONSUMER.INTIMESTAMP", Long.toString(intimestamp));
        map.put("WM_SEC.KEY_VERSION", priviateKeyVersion);

        String[] array = canonicalize(map);

        String data = null;

        try {
            data = generator.generateSignature(privateKey, array[1]);
        } catch(Exception e) { }
        System.out.println("Signature: " + data);
    }
    public String generateSignature(String key, String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Signature signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");

        ServiceKeyRep keyRep = new ServiceKeyRep(KeyRep.Type.PRIVATE, "RSA", "PKCS#8", Base64.decodeBase64(key));

        PrivateKey resolvedPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyRep.readResolve();

        signatureInstance.initSign(resolvedPrivateKey);

        byte[] bytesToSign = stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8");
        signatureInstance.update(bytesToSign);
        byte[] signatureBytes = signatureInstance.sign();

        String signatureString = Base64.encodeBase64String(signatureBytes);

        return signatureString;
    }
    protected static String[] canonicalize(Map<String, String> headersToSign) {
        StringBuffer canonicalizedStrBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer parameterNamesBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        Set<String> keySet=headersToSign.keySet();

        // Create sorted key set to enforce order on the key names
        SortedSet<String> sortedKeySet=new TreeSet<String>(keySet);
        for (String key :sortedKeySet) {
            Object val=headersToSign.get(key);
            parameterNamesBuffer.append(key.trim()).append(";");
            canonicalizedStrBuffer.append(val.toString().trim()).append("\n");
        }
        return new String[] {parameterNamesBuffer.toString(), canonicalizedStrBuffer.toString()};
    }

    class ServiceKeyRep extends KeyRep  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7213340660431987616L;
        public ServiceKeyRep(Type type, String algorithm, String format, byte[] encoded) {
            super(type, algorithm, format, encoded);
        }
        protected Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
            return super.readResolve();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a PHP equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Please mask the consumerId and private key when posting on forums. Please re-generate a new one.

Regarding your question, use this
https://github.com/fillup/walmart-auth-signature-php/blob/master/src/Signature.php

Comment: Those are straight from walmart, not my own values. I masked regardless.